# How do I use variable in script that is expecting text string?

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm using a third party widget to display stock market info on my website based on the stock ticker it gets passed.  But I don't want to hard code the ticker.  Instead I want it to be dynamic based on a parameter in the page's URL.  So far I have this code in the header:

```
<script>
    function GetTicker() 
    {
        const queryString = window.location.search;
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        // get the required parameter
        var ticker = urlParams.get('symbol'); 
        // returns the value of parameter 'symbol'
        document.getElementById("myTicker").innerHTML = ticker; 
    }
    </script>
```

It's working fine to parse the ticker from the URL as when I use this code in the body it displays the ticker from the page's URL:

```
<body onload="GetTicker()">
    The value for myTicker is: <scan id="myTicker"></scan><br>
</body>
```

How do I now use this in the widget's code instead of the hard coded ticker:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://thewidgetwebsite.com/theirpage.js" async>
    {
    "symbol": "ticker_expected_here"
    }
</script>
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://thewidgetwebsite.com/theirpage.js" async>
    {
    "symbol": ticker
    }
</script>
```

Where ticker is your variable containing the symbol?

It seems you need to brush up on "JavaScript objects".

Comment: Yes, that was one of the first thing I tried.  Below is the entire section.  I need more than brushing up, I'm completely new to this.   ;-).           symbol-info.js" async>
  {
  "symbol": ticker,
  "width": 1000,
  "locale": "en",
  "colorTheme": "light",
  "isTransparent": false
}